# What is so special around 0.36 when doing X to the power of X, when X < 0?

Tags: limits, derivatives

We all know that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}x^x = 1$ but what puzzles me is what is happening on the way to x=0. We first have a downward slope, ending around x=0.36, then it is increasing again up to 1. Not a smooth U formed shape either. I guess it has something to do with $\frac{1}{e}$ but what explains this curve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but your question seems to be, "why does $x^x$ have a minimum around $0.36$?" We can compute its derivative:
$$
(x^x)' = x^x (1+\log(x))
$$This is zero exactly when $\log(x)=-1$, i.e. $x=e^{-1}\approx 0.3679$. Further, this is a minimum because the second derivative is $x^x(1/x+(1+\log(x)^2)$, which is positive at $x=e^{-1}$.